# PHP MySQL select all results with ASC references

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

Suppose I have the following table:

```
ID|Reference
1 |23
1 |27
1 |47
1 |48
2 |16
2 |17
2 |18
2 |33
3 |16
3 |19
3 |22
4 |2
5 |6
5 |8
5 |7
5 |12
```

I want to select all the ID's that have at least 2 ASC references with a difference of 1. So for instance when I execute the query, I want a return of:

```
ID|Reference
1 |47
1 |48
2 |16
2 |17
2 |18
5 |6
5 |8
5 |7
```

Ofcourse, I could use a query like:

```
SELECT ID, Reference FROM Table ORDER BY Reference ASC
```

and loop through the results and check it manually. However, I am wondering whether MySQL could achieve this in a single query and pop back the right results, since this will optimize performance (I guess)

Answer (score 0):

It is strange a field called ID that is not unique, you probably have a good reason.

You can try with a query like

```
SELECT ID, Reference FROM Table WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table T WHERE T.ID = Table.ID AND T.Reference = Table.Reference - 1) OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table T WHERE T.ID = Table.ID AND T.Reference = Table.Reference + 1)
```

That means "get elements that have another element with same ID and a Reference with distance 1 (lower or higer)". It will not return exactly the ID's (you can try with SELECT DISTINTC(ID)...) it will return a result like your example with ID, Reference pairs where IDs will be not unique.

I am not sure if this will be more efficient, it probably depends on how many records you have in your table and how many records will match your condition.

Good luck.

Comment: I indeed have a good reason and it still is a unique ID but in another table. I would like to minimize the joines of other tabels, to optimize performance. Because it will be executing in large tables

Answer (score 0):

Joins should be fast if you have useful indexes.

I would suggest just doing a couple of simple queries (using simple joins) , and unioning the results together

```
SELECT T1.ID, 
        T1.Reference 
FROM Table T1
INNER JOIN Table T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
AND T1.Reference = T2.Reference + 1
UNION
SELECT T1.ID, 
        T1.Reference 
FROM Table T1
INNER JOIN Table T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
AND T1.Reference = T2.Reference - 1
ORDER BY Reference ASC
```

Comment: What about searching a table of over 500k rows? (multiple ID's multiple words and multiple references)

Comment: If indexes on ID and reference then probably should still perform OK (not sure what the _multiple words_ refers to though, as not something mentioned in the original question). Although a large factor will be the number of records returned.